# Verify if patches are present in linux-kernel

Tags: git, linux-kernel

I'm trying to figure out a solution where you could take the linux-next or any linux kernel branch and search if a certain set of patches (patch files) are present in the code or not.
This would presumable involve doing a git pull of the kernel tree, which is not a problem, but I'm not sure on how to do a batch search/compare if some patches are included.

Should this be done with the actual .patch files, or searching for the IDs of the commits is enough?
Can someone please provide me with some sort of code or references to how this can be achieved?
Thank you!

Comment: It's a non-trivial task since many patches could touch the very same files sequentially in the upstream. The quite rough approach is try to apply them via git apply.

Comment: Thanks Andy, we would assume that only a recent set of patches are wanted to be verified, and the kernel files are not changed from other sources, so the variables of the problem are limited, so I don't want to add too much complexity for the time being.

Comment: You probably never tried such things. Many times when I was working on some driver or kernel module I created a series of patches. After submitting them and merging in upstream (okay, linux-next was reflecting the changes few days later after submission happened), I rebased my local branch. More than one third cases were failed. It means you can't do this automatically, rather to get some heuristics     and decide if patch was in upstream or not. For example, try to apply them in reversed chronological order. But you have to split them to logical 'series' beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the manual approach is sufficient. If you know a file touched by the patch and the content of some changed line you can do:

```
git log -p remotes/origin/next -- path/to/file
```

this will give you the whole history of that file and you can search (<kbd>/</kbd>)  for the changed line manually.

Once you found the ID of the commit in question you can use `git show $id` to list the whole commit and compare it against your patch file.